# ColdFusion 2016 server on W2K12 / IIS - 500 errors on anything BUT .cfm files

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

This server is (was) being prepped to move to production last week, but started giving 500 errors on files that are not .cfm files - i.e. .htm, .css, .js files all give 500 errors (but not in CFAdmin).

It's a vanilla install and followed the lockdown guide carefully.  It was working fine until yesterday when I had some issues.

1 - it took 3 tries to install HF4 from command line.  it would seem like it worked fine but when I went back into CFAdmin it still showed the previous version.  I did it again today and it installed fine and now shows correct version.

2 - initially it was setup so that only one specific site was setup in wsconfig.  I added a site and it wouldn't serve cfm pages.  Ran wsconfig.exe as Administrator, removed all connectors, and then did an add for all IIS sites.  Again, seemed to work fine and CFM pages can be served now, but nothing else.

There's nothing standing out to me in IIS, and no config changes were done to IIS (at least by me - if the Adobe installer or wsconfig did then I'm at a loss).

Comment: Have you viewed the page directly from the server so you can get better information on the error that is occuring? or looked at any logs? would certainly help to know what the error is when trying to fix an error. Otherwise... you're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: I second the above.  Check the event viewer.
Also, check that you don't have any items in your web.config that are duplicates of your parent config.
Check for handler mappings for dynamic files (php/asp)
Check mime-types for .htm files

Comment: I agree with the above. 500 errors are great for displaying to an end user, but for the actual developer or admin, it's basically like the server telling you "Oops, something broke." Check the server logs to get more information on what the 500 error is covering up. You can't fix it until you know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So browsing locally was revealing!

> Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'mimeMap' with unique
>   key attribute 'fileExtension' set to '.air'

Looking in web.config I found this entry for both sites:

```
<staticContent>
   mimeMap fileExtension=".air" mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip" /
</staticContent>
```

Both sites had been working just fine until I ran the CF2016 HF4 update.  I'm curious if this entry was added by the update installer?